# LM1084, should I leave the copper area connected to the TAB floating?

Tags: voltage-regulator, temperature, layout, cooling

I am using the [LM1084](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1084.pdf) in a DDPAK package as a 5V USB voltage regulator on 4-layer board. 
The TAB of the package is internaly connected to pin 2 (OUTPUT).

[image: LM1084 DDPAK/TO-263 package]

I am not sure what to do with the copper area connected to the TAB. Which of the following options should I choose:

1. **leave** the copper area connected to the TAB **floating**
2. **connect** the copper area connected to the TAB **to pin 2** (OUTPUT)
3. **use** the copper area connected to the TAB **as a the primary OUTPUT** connection, **leave pin 2 floating**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The datasheet should give a recommended layout, but if not then the general rule of thumb is to connect the tab with pin 2, then you can use either the tab or pin 2, or even both, to act as your output.

For instance, this is the recommended layout for a CAT4101 in a 5-pin D²PAK:

[image]

And, while it's not the same footprint, the same principal applies to SOT223, as in this recent layout of mine:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a voltage regulator and they work best when the temperature varies the least amount so, maximize your copper area: -

[image]

Maximizing your copper area means making use of every trick and that includes tying the tab copper to pin2 copper.

For a copper area of 1000 sq mm (32mm x 32mm) the device will warm up 45 degC for each internal watt dissipated. At 2000 sq mm this is down to 33 degC / watt. More is better.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing me to this diagram, that is very helpful.